# Rmi client connection check and retrying to connect?

Tags: java, connection, client, rmi

I'm using RMI and I have a server object and many clients that connected to server.
My question is about client connections.
How can I check client connections disconnected ?
If a client disconnected it should try to re-connect the server ?

Is there any example that is useful about connection checking and and re-connection ?

I have come up hearbeat offer ? Is it best solution ?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connections in RMI are managed automatically, and completely hidden from you. The only control you have over them is via the RMI system properties listed in the [Javadoc/Guide to Features/RMI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/index.html).

Comment: if connection broken how it warns me without remote method call.

Comment: @emin It doesn't 'warn you without remote method call'. RMI throws a RemoteException in the client while doing a method call. If the server detects a broken connection it just closes the socket and continues.